# Handling Variables To Be Used Across Functions Without Global Variables

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

So I'm working on a basic word game where you're dealt a "hand" (a dictionary object) of letters that you use to create words and get points.

This "hand" is used in the parameters of a number of functions: calculating a player's score, updating the number of letters in a hand after a player has used one or more letters, displaying the hand, checking the validity of the player's word, etc.

From all that I've read, I know that I should avoid global variables if I can (though I'm still not totally sure why).

So what other general approach could I use for a number of functions that use "hand" as a parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called an object. Create a [class](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) with the shared state, and the functions that share that state.

The reason why this is better than global variables is that it's a much more restricted version of the same concept - you can clearly see which functions are manipulating those variables, and document (and enforce) the expected invariants on those variables. With global variables it ends up being quite easy to have functions which have different expectations about the state of the shared variables.

It also allows you to have multiple copies of the same object, so instead of having to cast your variables as collections, and correlate between members of the collection, you have a collection of objects, which makes your code simpler. *It is then a simple matter to manipulate those objects only through the functions you have defined*.

Answer (score 8):

Use class encapusulation ... see below ... game is aware of both hands

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
       num_cards = 7
       self.cards = ["a" for i in range(num_cards)]

class Game:
    def __init__(self,num_hands=2):
        self.hands = [Hand() for i in range(num_hands)]
        self.current_turn = 0 
    def play(self):
        self.hands[self.current_turn].play()
        self.current_turn = (self.current_turn+1)%len(self.hands)
```

This is Python 3 code; classes in Python 2 should derive from `object`.

... although they are not required to. if they do not they lose some functionality

Comment: Well, you bump up against odd corners if you use old-style classes. That said, you can also the module-level `__metaclass__` to make everything new-style.

Comment: I keep hearing that but I have yet to run into much weirdness using old style classes (but I did mention in py2 you should inherit from object)  do you have any links to specific weirdness using old style classes?

Comment: The main issue is that `super` may not play nicely; explicit type handling will not work as one might expect; and any code which relies on magic will break (which I guess covers the previous two items). I use `super` enough that it really seems like a win. If you never, or rarely need to inherit from your own classes, it's not likely to be an issue. And if it is, the fix is easy. I suppose I should have said that *may* bump up against odd corners. The real issue is that such issues are hard to diagnose.

Comment: yeah I typically do explicit inheritance `MyParentClass.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)`  type thing ... even though I know its frowned upon.  (tbh I probably use it because of the `super` weirdness on old style classes)

Comment: Oh, and apparently dunder methods on new-style objects are not looked-up through `__getattr__`.