# Alternatives to the global statement in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a very simple roulette simulator, only focusing on red/black betting (basically like a game of heads or tails).

The issue I have is with variables being called across functions.

Here is the code (I'm sure it has other issues too, but I'm focusing on this one, for now):

```
import random

# Defines initial amounts of money and losses
money = 50
losses = 0

# Starts the sim
def roulette_sim():
    print "How much do you want to bet?"
    bet = int(raw_input("> "))   
    if bet > money:
        bet_too_much()
    else:
        red_or_black()


# Prevents one from betting more money than one has
def bet_too_much():
    print "You do not have all that money. Please bet again." 
    raw_input("Press ENTER to continue> ")
    roulette_sim()

# Asks user to select red or black, starts the sim, modifies money/losses
def red_or_black():
    print "OK, you bet %r" %  (bet)
    print "Red or black?"
    answer = raw_input("> ")
    number = random.randint(1, 2)
    if number == 1 and answer == "red":
        print "You win!"
        money += bet
        print "You now have %r money" % (money)
        print "Your losses are %r" % (losses)
        replay()
    elif number == 2 and answer == "black":
        print "You win!"
        money += bet
        print "You now have %r money" % (money)
        print "Your losses are %r" % (losses)
        replay()
    else:
        print "You lost!"
        money -= bet
        losses += bet
        print "You now have %r money" % (money)
        print "Your losses are %r" % (losses)
        replay()

# Asks user whether he/she wants to play again
def replay():
    print "Do you want to play again?"
    play_again = raw_input("y/n> ")
    if play_again == "y":
        roulette_sim()
    else:
        print "OK, bye loser!"


roulette_sim()
```

So, I get `NameError: global name 'bet' is not defined`, which I could avoid by using `global`, but I'd rather not resort to that. How can I call this variable, with the value assigned to it by the user in `roulette_sim`, in the other functions, other than via using `global`?

I suppose the same issue would apply to the `money` variable.

I currently have an extremely basic knowledge of Python, so I apologise for any mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: You would be better off if you encapsulate everything in a class and do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Variables To Be Used Across Functions Without Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482237/handling-variables-to-be-used-across-functions-without-global-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the values as arguments to functions and make the functions *return* the updated values, e.g:

```
def roulette_sim(money, losses):
    print "How much do you want to bet?"
    bet = int(raw_input("> "))   
    if bet > money:
        return bet_too_much(money, losses)
    else:
        eturn red_or_black(money, losses, bet)
```

Where `red_or_black` instead of modifying the global `money` and `losses` variables it passes the amount of lost moey to `replay` which calls `roulette_sim` with the updated values.

Alternatively you can simply put everything into a class and use `self.money`, `self.losses` and `self.bet` as "globals".

**However** you may notice that the whole design of these functions is *awful*.
They have complicated relations and they use recursion, which means that after (probably less than) 1000 bets you'll receive a `RuntimError: Maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

You could refactor the whole code to use loops instead.
Just to give an idea:

```
import random



def get_bet():
    bet = float('+inf')
    while bet > money:
        print("How much do you want to bet?")
        bet = int(raw_input("> "))
        if bet > money:
            bet_too_much()
    return bet

def bet_too_much():
    print("you do not have all the money. Please bet again.")
    raw_input("Press ENTER to continue")


def roulette_sim():
    money = 50
    losses = 0
    while True:
        bet = get_bet()
        won = red_or_black(bet)
        money += won
        losses -= won
```

**Note:** Imagine that you want to write a different game where the player bets.
Using your design it's *really* hacky to re-use the functions in this new game.

With the above design you can freely re-use the `get_bet()` function to asks the player a bet etc.
This just to give yet another reason to use loops instead of tightly coupling functions with recursion cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Use a class:

```
import random

class RouletteSim(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Defines initial amounts of money and losses
        self.money = 50
        self.losses = 0

    # Starts the sim
    def roulette_sim(self):
        print "How much do you want to bet?"
        bet = int(raw_input("> "))
        if bet > self.money:
            self.bet_too_much()
        else:
            self.red_or_black(bet)

    # Prevents one from betting more money than one has
    def bet_too_much(self):
        print "You do not have all that money. Please bet again."
        raw_input("Press ENTER to continue> ")
        self.roulette_sim()

    # Asks user to select red or black, starts the sim, modifies money/losses
    def red_or_black(self, bet):
        print "OK, you bet %r" %  (bet)
        print "Red or black?"
        answer = raw_input("> ")
        number = random.randint(1, 2)
        if number == 1 and answer == "red":
            print "You win!"
            self.money += bet
            print "You now have %r money" % (self.money)
            print "Your losses are %r" % (self.losses)
            self.replay()
        elif number == 2 and answer == "black":
            print "You win!"
            self.money += bet
            print "You now have %r money" % (self.money)
            print "Your losses are %r" % (self.losses)
            self.replay()
        else:
            print "You lost!"
            self.money -= bet
            self.losses += bet
            print "You now have %r money" % (self.money)
            print "Your losses are %r" % (self.losses)
            self.replay()

    # Asks user whether he/she wants to play again
    def replay(self):
        print "Do you want to play again?"
        play_again = raw_input("y/n> ")
        if play_again == "y":
            self.roulette_sim()
        else:
            print "OK, bye loser!"

RouletteSim().roulette_sim()
```

Answer (score 1):

bet is valid variable in roulette_sim function 
but in red_or_black function you started using it by first at

```
print "OK, you bet %r" %  (bet)
```

and then

```
money += bet
```

and etc that is not valid, you should pass your bet as argument to red_or_black 
call that function as follows:

```
red_or_black(bet)   # bet is argument
```

and define it as:

```
def red_or_black(bet):   # bet is parameter
```

and everything will be ok